# Running svn update script on docker container start

Tags: svn, docker, jenkins, dockerfile

I have a dockerfile which describes a jenkins slave. In this slave I need to checkout some files in order to have our build work. To have this folder always up to date I intended to do a svn update each time the container starts. But it doesn't work for some reason. Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
...
# Arguments which can be passed via --build-arg <varname>=<value>
ARG svnPassword
ARG svnUser
...
#Install Subversion
RUN apt-get install -y subversion

# Checkout config from SVN
RUN mkdir -p /home/jenkins/workspace/config && cd /home/jenkins/workspace && svn checkout --username $svnUser --password $svnPassword http://myRepo/config
...
# Add svnUpdate.sh script
ADD svnUpdate.sh /home/svnUpdate.sh

CMD /home/svnUpdate.sh $svnUser $svnPassword
```

My svnUpdate.sh looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/sbin/sshd -D
cd /home/jenkins/workspace/config && svn update --username $1 --password $2
```

What I don't understand is: When I log into my running container and execute

```
./home/svnUpdate.sh user password
```

it works perfectly. What do I need to change so that the script is getting executed on container startup?

UPDATE: 
It turns out that the "/usr/sbin/sshd -D" of the script blocks the script to continue.

I also changed it to use ENTRYPOINT instead of CMD:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "./home/svnUpdate.sh", "$svnUser", "$svnPassword"]
```

now my only problem is that the String "$svnUser" is passed to the script instead of the resolved value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the ARG values can't be used at runtime as they're build arguments. My workaround is to save them in an Environment variable in the Dockerfile:

```
...
ENV SVN_USER $svnUser
ENV SVN_PW $svnPassword
...
```

and use it in the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/jenkins/workspace/config && svn update --username $SVN_USER --password $SVN_PW
unset SVN_USER
unset SVN_PW
/usr/sbin/sshd -D
```